# Spawning a "Pokemon" type graph in php from MYSQL data

Tags: php, mysql, graph

If you remember when you check your pokemon's stats (In Red, Blue, Yellow, Silver, Gold etc.), the graph that it generates scales based on the HP, attack, defense, special attack, and special defense of your pokemon.

I want to generate a graph such as this using PHP and MYSQL for in-office personnel data. I thought it would be cool to create a stat card/sheet for each employee showing their strengths and weaknesses based on their experience with different subjects of their work.

Anyone have an idea how I may accomplish this? If it can't be done w/PHP what can I use?

Comment: For those of us who haven't played Pokemon, could you include a screenshot?  Also, what have you got so far?

Comment: Must... +1... for Pokémon reference...

Comment: Actually not R/B/Y. I played it this morning and I'm positive that there isn't such cool graphs.

Comment: If my manager handed me a card with my weaknesses on it and it had a picture of a pokémon, I wouldn't even put in my two weeks. I'd just leave. Just sayin'.

Comment: maybe it's the newer versions... i can't find a pic of it by googling for the life of me. I'll find another example

Comment: @Mechaflash Something like that ? http://www.theschlock.com/daily/pages/s_mus2.gif

Comment: While @glowcoder's hatred of Pokemon is clearly irrational, they're bringing up something important -- if you're bring up people's weaknesses, doing it in a "cute" way is just going to make them more unhappy about it.

Comment: @BrendanLong it's more or less for showing areas that the employee accels in. And this isn't to show to the employee themselves, but for management to help with human capital allocation. Why keep someone who's weak working on tasks that they take too long to complete or make too many mistakes doing. Move them over to what they work on better, and rotate someone else to perform the tasks they are weak in.

Comment: @Glowcoder i just might match them up with a pokemon =D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are called [Radar/Spider Charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) and there are a [variety](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=exemple8) of [libraries](http://marcosfedato.blogspot.com/2011/10/jquery-visualize-radar-chart-english.html) and [tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/radar_charts.html) you can use to make them.

[image]

[Image from Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spider_Chart2.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the links! Nailed it for me.

Comment: I hope they point you in the right direction. Common problem to solve, hard to know what they are called/search on it, so there are lots of libraries.